# Android need help to sort saving images from web

Tags: android, image, gallery, datecreated

I have a problem when saving image from web.

I create new folder and save all images to this. The problem is I want this folder order by the last download image on first but When i open gallery, the folder is order by the image date created and the date created in the downloaded image is not the time I download but the first time it created. I've already search on stack over flow and see that java can't modified the date created in image to the time I download it.

Any one has the solution? (Sorry for the bad English)

Thanks you for the comment. I will explain more details.

First, I download image from web to cache directory

```
HttpURLConnection localHttpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openConnection(); 
localHttpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
localHttpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(30000);
localHttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
InputStream in = localHttpURLConnection.getInputStream();
File localFile = Constans.fileCache.getCacheFile(urldisplay);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(localFile);
Utils.CopyStream(in, fos); // simple copy by trunks
fos.close();
```

Second, I copy downloaded image to external storage

```
File toFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder", "folder_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(toFile);
Utils.CopyStream(new FileInputStream(fromFile), fos);
fos.close();

// Scan image to display when open with gallery otherwise it couldn't see in gallery
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(toFie);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
mContext.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

Lastly, I see that gallery don't sort my image by the time I downloaded. That is the problem i want to fix.

Comment: Please add some code, and details.
are you using android's galary or galary view ?

Comment: Thank iu for answer me. I've explained more details. Could you give more help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood, but let's try.

First the issue you mention is more specific to Gallery application than a java code issue. 
I assume Gallery use EXIF information to order the picture by date they were taken, not oder they are downloaded/copied. Unfortunatly Gallery does not provide any option to sort picture in other oders.

Maybe you can try to use another explorer that allows you to sort the pictures in another order (maybe ESFileExplore which has more options?)

Ultimate solution: you can try to change EXIF in your pictures using a java EXIF library to modify picture taken date and this should change the order they appear in the Galery (but very ugly solution...). Some random EXIF libraries after 5 seconds of Google:
http://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/
http://www.toanthang.net/modules.php?name=News&new_topic=2&catid=7

Hope this helps
Thierry

Comment: Thank iu for answer me. I've explained more details. Could you give more help?

Comment: ok. as I told, gallery sort image by date picture taken, not by date downloaded. This is like this and you can't change this. 

If you absolutly want to sort by download date in the gallery, the hack I mentionned is to modify EXIF information using one of these EXIF libraries in your picture to modify  date taken of the picture and replace it by the download date after you saved them. in this case they will be sorted the way you want. However it is pretty hugly as it changes the nature of exif information.